# Sum Group By Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column (PL.UNITS) that I need to Total at the bottom of the results of a query, is it possible to sum PL.UNITS that is already summed?

Please see query below.

```
SELECT ID.DUEDATE AS [DUE DATE], CD.RENEWALDATE, CD.RENEWALSTATUS, CD.CONTRACTNUMBER, L.LOCNAME, L.LOCADDRESS1, L.LOCADDRESS2, L.LOCADDRESS3, L.LOCADDRESS4, L.POSTCODE, SUM(PL.UNITS) AS UNITS from CLIENTDETAILS CD 

INNER JOIN LOCATIONS L ON CD.CLIENTNUMBER = L.CLIENTNUMBER 
INNER JOIN ITEMDETAILS ID ON L.LOCNUMBER = ID.LOCNUMBER
INNER JOIN PLANT PL ON ID.CODE = PL.CODE

WHERE L.OWNER = 210 and L.STATUSLIVE = 1 and ID.DUEDATE > '01/01/2017' 

GROUP BY ID.DUEDATE, CD.RENEWALDATE, CD.RENEWALSTATUS, CD.CONTRACTNUMBER, L.LOCNAME, L.LOCADDRESS1, L.LOCADDRESS2, L.LOCADDRESS3, L.LOCADDRESS4, L.POSTCODE
```

Comment: please post some sample data and output how you want

Comment: Look for how to implement [`ROLLUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx) in sqlserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to do this sort of thing in front end development. Nevertheless, here is an example (quick and dirty, but shows the idea) for sql-server:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.id, 'total') AS id
,       SUM(a.thing) AS thing_summed
FROM    (
            SELECT '1' id
            ,   1 thing
            UNION
            SELECT '2'
            ,   2 thing
            UNION
            SELECT '1'
            ,   3 thing
        ) AS a
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a.id)
```

Result:

```
+-------+--------------+
|  id   | thing_summed |
+-------+--------------+
| 1     |            4 |
| 2     |            2 |
| total |            6 |
+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer, it is to be used in a WPF application, but I was just doing some testing on SQL to start with.  Thanks for the solution.